# How to switch IconTabBar in OPA5 tests

Tags: automated-tests, qunit, sapui5

My view contains a [IconTabBar](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabBar.html) with various [IconTabFilters](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabFilter.html).

How can I switch the currently active tab to another one? The usual `trigger("tap")` approach does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I figured out that pseudo event `saptouchend` triggered on the icon within the `IconTabFilter` works.

```
return this.waitFor({
    id: "mySecondTab-icon",
    viewName: sViewName,
    success: function (control) {
        control.$().trigger("saptouchend");
    },
    errorMessage: "Second IconTabFilter not found in IconTabBar"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your solution

Normally I look at the QUnit tests for the control and hope they have done something similar

eg

```
// Press SPACE key on second IconTabFilter to expand 
sap.ui.test.qunit.triggerKeydown(oControl.$(), jQuery.sap.KeyCodes.SPACE);
```

UPDATE:
just noticed a solution in the [TEST Tutorial](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/testing/14/webapp/test/integration/pages/Post.js#L25) - not sure i like it though as it doesn't simulate user interaction

```
iPressOnTheTabWithTheKey: function (sKey) {
    return this.waitFor({
        id: "iconTabBar",
        viewName : sViewName,
        success: function (oIconTabBar) {
            oIconTabBar.setSelectedKey(sKey);
        },
        errorMessage: "Cannot find the icon tab bar"
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that can we to use the id/icon to pick the iconTab which you want and then add a action to it, which in your case will be a press.

`iClickOnSecondIconTabBAr: function() {
        return this.waitFor({
                controlType: "sap.m.IconTabFilter",
                matchers: new sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties({
                     icon: "sap-icon://inspection"
                }),
                actions: new Press(),
                errorMessage: "Did not find the IconTabBar Button!"
        });
}`